# How to de/serialize nested objects with Json.Net

Tags: c#, json, json.net

Let's say I have two classes, namely Person and Project:

```
class Person {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

class Project {
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Workers { get; set; }
}
```

I want to store person data and project data in separate files named person.json and project.json.

To serialize the data I use the statement below:

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Collection, Formatting.None, new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };)
```

where collection is a `List<People>`.

To deserialize the person data I use the statement below:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<T>>(json, , new JsonSerializerSettings()
    {
        NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
    };)
```

where json is the string json data from the person.json.
I display the `List<Person>` in a ListBox.

Now I'm not sure how I should store the project data so that every time I edit an person object and eventually save it to the person.json file, the respective person object in the `List<Person>` object in the project file also updates.

I'm not even sure whether json is a good way to do that or not and maybe I should try a relational database.

Please let me know if I haven't explained my situation well. I really need to do the job with json and looking for a solution for my problem. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You need to rewrite the JSON file with new content. And yes, it sounds like a relational database is more appropriate. JSON and XML is *transport* formats, they're not ideal as *storage* formats.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen - Plenty of systems use JSON as a storage format.  What he's asking requires a management layer for the data, regardless of format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't really targeted at serialization, but rather at synchronization of the data.  Consider for a moment that you would have the same issue if you were use XML, text files, or some custom binary format.

Since you have denormalized the `Person` object into the `Project` object, then every time you save a project, it will have a full copy of all of the person data.

One option would be to *not* denormalize, and instead just put a list of `PersonID` into the `Project` object.  Depending on which path was more prominent in your app, you could also consider adding a list of `ProjectID` into the Person object.  In other words, the relationship may be able to be expressed either way.

One way or another, you'll need something to manage your data.  It could be that you write a bunch of code to load all of the JSON files from disk and manipulate it yourself.  It could be that you map your structured data to a relational schema that could be stored in a database like SQL Server or MySQL.  You might use an ORM like EntityFramwork or NHibernate to help with that.  Alternatively, you could use one of the NoSQL databases like RavenDB or MongoDB, or many other similar projects.

In other words - keep the ideas of serialization and storage separated.  Sometimes serialization is involved in storage, but serialization is also involved in transport, and many storage engines deal with serialization in their own custom ways.